# Use Task.Delay in an always true while loop for pause sending post requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, webforms, task, telegram-bot

I've written a telegram bot using webforms, that there is always true while loop and a thread is always posting to api.telegram.org/bottoken/getupdates to a get json format array of 100 updates.

the host config of my robot is not sufficient for handling for example 200 concurrent telegram robot requests.
so i ended up with an idea to improve the concurrent user numbers and give time to execute what they need. please tell me if it is true or completely wrong.

i used a `await Task.Delay(150)` in my while loop after getting each updates, so the while thread will go back to thread pool(??) and the program has 150 more milliseconds to handle for example 100 requests and then go for next update array comes from telegram.

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
    await Get100UpdatesAndProcess();//database works, sending answers etc...
    await Task.Delay(150);
}
```

is there any problems with this work i.e. performance issues, memory leak, being useless, thread wasting,,,

thanks

Comment: There is no code so nobody can check for 'performance issues, memory leak, being useless, thread wasting'. Post what you have done and what doesn't work that you want to do

Comment: @JakubDąbek My bad, Code Uploaded

Comment: `await Get100UpdatesAndProcess();` blocks until the processing is completed and the `Task.Delay(150);` starts after that. You can do `var task = Get100UpdatesAndProcess(); await Task.Delay(150); await task;`. Also `Get100UpdatesAndProcess` should be called `Get100UpdatesAndProcessAsync` if it's really asynchronous

Comment: The Async at the end of the name is a good practice.

Comment: @JakubDąbek actually I'm using an event to handle each update individually, but that was a great point u mentioned, thanks

                    `foreach (var update in updates)`  
                    `{`  
                        `OnUpdateReceived(new UpdateEventArgs(update));`
                        `MessageOffset = update.Id + 1;`
                    `}`

Comment: @SadraRahmani Are you actually putting the work from `Get100UpdatesAndProcess` on another thread or a thread-pool and leaving it be? If not, the `Task.Delay(150)` is useless because you block in the loop waiting for `Get100UpdatesAndProcess` to finish anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems right and I can not foresee any memory leak or something.
One minor change could be to avoid 2 sync from the TPL:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await Get100UpdatesAndProcess().ContinueWith(t => Task.Delay(150));
}
```

But anyway, the long running task nowadays are processed in 2 steps: the reception and the processing. If you have a queue system at hand like (MSMQ, Rabbit MQ) you can split your task in a producer consumer-like style.
You will see your application being fault tolerant, distributable and in general more decouple.

Your code will look like this:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var updates = await Get100Updates();
    foreach (var upt in updates)
    {
        Q.Enqueue(upt); // This is referring to the Queueing System, don't take it literally
    }
}
```

and in a different thread or node or app

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var upt = Q.Dequeue() // Get pending update for processing
    await Process(upt);
}
```

with this style, you are using almost all the CPU time available and have no unused delay.